# Как адаптировать кнопку?

Tags: html, css

https://uzinouzi.github.io/perila/ - Верстка.
Кнопка становиться по верх логотипа и бургера, хотя в потоке она стоит после бургера и логотипа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И еще один вопрос, это нормально что верстка так крашится на моб устройствах (я пока почти ничего не адаптивил), либо это уже надо как-то учитывать при верстке десктопа, что бы как-то все более менее само адаптировалось? И может есть какие-нибудь явные ошибки в верстке, укажите на них, был бы очень благодарен.

Comment: Почему бы сразу было не сверстать с помощью какого нибудь bootstrap. Облегчили бы себе работы.
У вас у logo стоит float:left; поэтому кнопка там и находится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы нарушаете поток используя float,поведение блока с классом .request_call вполне предсказуемо.
Вы используете свойство float:none,тем самым элемент выводится как обычно.Чтобы разобраться,советую вам в блоке с классом .logo у тега img поставить заглушку src="#" и удалить альтернативный текст.
По поводу всей верстки,думаю Вы ошиблись форумом.